# Hive and regular expressions

Tags: regex, hive

I need to extract

> AP-LOGO-140609131400-PR-WB-OT-MR-18_Logo

from the following string:

> example.com/?it_category=AP&it_action=WB-LOGO&it_label=AP-LOGO-140609131400-PR-WB-OT-MR-18_Logo&it_value=0

using hive regular expressions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
it_label=([^&]*)
```

Comment: Your post has been flagged for quality review because it is a code-only answer. Please read [answer].